# Clamp a forward vector to a specific range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, angle, clamp

Right now, I have a 360 degree camera that rotates around the player. I currently get the angle between the player's forward and the camera's forward and this works correctly. If the camera is directly behind the player the angle returns 0, and when the camera is in front of the player and looking towards the player, it returns 180.

```
 void AngleBetweenCameraAndPlayer()
    {
            var playerAngle = _playerTransform.forward;
            var camAngle = _cameraTransform.forward;
            playerAngle.y = 0;
            camAngle.y = 0;
            var horizDiffAngle = Vector3.Angle(playerAngle, camAngle);
    }
```

I shoot the ball using .AddForce on its rigidbody, and the ball moves in the direction of the cameras forward.

```
_ballrb.AddForce(_cameraForward * (power * _timer), ForceMode.Impulse);  // projects the ball forward relative to the camera's forward by x power and x time held down.
```

I then in a separate method draw the balls trajectory using a kinematic equation. This script is attached to the ball gameObject and works correctly.

```
   private void DrawProjection()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = Mathf.CeilToInt(linePoints / timeBetweenPoints) + 1;
        Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;
        Vector3 startVelocity = _cameraForward* (power * _timer);
        int i = 0;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, startPosition);
        

         for (float time = 0; time < linePoints; time += timeBetweenPoints)
         {
             i++;
             Vector3 point = startPosition + time * startVelocity;
             point.y = startPosition.y + startVelocity.y * time +   (Physics.gravity.y/2f  * Mathf.Pow(time, 2));
             
             lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, point);
         }
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that when the player is trying to kick a ball, I want the angle of which it can shoot to be locked/ clamped 45 degrees from the players forward, and when you go past 45 degrees, you can still shoot, but it will be locked at that 45 degree angle.

Some ideas I've had is to clamp the _cameraForward by that angle and not let the angle go past 45 degrees, or using an if statement saying that if the angle is less than 45 degrees you can shoot and it will project the line, but the issue is when you go past 45 degrees, you can no longer shoot and it wont project and this is not what I want. I still want you to be able to shoot and project, just locked at that 45 degree angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly (imho improved) way of [Serlite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75587846/7111561) would be to not go through `Quaternion` but directly stay with `Vector3`.

There is [`Vector3.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) which is specifically for **directions** and maintains the same magnitude all the time (other than `Vector3.Lerp`).

It also handles the clamping already since the factor is always clamped to be between `0` and `1`.

```
Vector3 GetDirectionWithinLimit(Vector3 initialDirection, Vector3 targetDirection, float maxAngle)
{
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(initialDirection, targetDirection);

    // You could probably keep this to save some work
    // otherwise `Vector3.Slerp` will anyway clamp the factor to be between `0` and `1`
    //// If angle is within the limit, no need to do further calculations
    //if (angle <= maxAngle)
    //{
    //    return targetDirection;
    //}

    // Factor will be 0 - 1 if angle > maxAngle
    // Otherwise factor will be > 1 but Slerp clamps it to 1 anyway
    float factor = maxAngle / angle;
    return Vector3.Slerp(initialDirection, targetDirection, factor);
}
```

Personally I would keep it that way but some people like one-liners ^^

```
Vector3 GetDirectionWithinLimit(Vector3 initialDirection, Vector3 targetDirection, float maxAngle) => Vector3.Slerp(initialDirection, targetDirection, maxAngle / Vector3.Angle(initialDirection, targetDirection));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Works just as I wanted it to work. The only thing I had to do differently was to have two different camAngles. One that has its .y set to zero to get the correct angle, and then I had to just use the camera.forward for shooting so it could shoot upwards.    (what I changed it to ->)     return Vector3.Slerp(_playerTransform.forward, camTransform.forward, factor);   Thank you so much!

Comment: My main question here if you dont mind answering it is what exactly is Vector3.Slerp of the initial and target direction by factor doing ? I've tried looking at unity docs and some threads but I'm not grasping the use of it perfectly. Could you explain how and what it is doing in this scenario? @derHugo

Comment: @RyanClark it is basically "spherical lerp" ... the `Vector.Lerp` interpolates between two **positions** => imagine having has directions `1, 0, 0` and `-1, 0, 0` => while lerping in the middle you would hit `0, 0, 0` which is not desired for a direction. The `Vector3.Slerp` rather maintains the magnitude by basically interpolating on a curve .. you can try to use it on a position and see what happens, basically it will orbit around a position in the middle between the two target values => for **directions** this basically results in a rotation toward the target direction

Answer (score 0):

You must have tried it, but when you calculate the angle just clamp it?

```
void AngleBetweenCameraAndPlayer()
    {
            var playerAngle = _playerTransform.forward;
            var camAngle = _cameraTransform.forward;
            playerAngle.y = 0;
            camAngle.y = 0;
            var horizDiffAngle = Vector3.Angle(playerAngle, camAngle);
            if (horizDiffAngle > 45)
                horizDiffAngle = 45
            else if (horizDiffAngle < -45)
                horizDiffAngle = -45

    }
```

Comment: The issue is not clamping the angle itself, its clamping the shooting by that angle. I currently get the angle, but I don't use it to relegate the shooting. That is my problem.

Comment: Then I'd look into [Quaternion.AngleAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html). Considering you want to apply the rotation respect the player's up axis I'd do:

`var shootDir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yourClampedAngle, _playerTransform.up);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick you can use when you want to limit a rotation (or change in direction) to a certain angle - use [Quaternion.Lerp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)! This allows you to generate a rotation that is partway in between two different rotations, which is useful if you want to calculate a rotation that is within a particular limit.

For example, if the angle between `_playerTransform.forward` and `_cameraTransform.forward` is 90 degrees, but your maximum angle is 45 degrees, then the parameters you'd want to pass in would be:

- a: The rotation to point along the player's forward, which you can calculate using [Quaternion.LookRotation()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)
- b: The rotation to point along the camera's forward
- t: The amount of the rotation that we allow - so if the raw rotation is 90 degrees, then this value would be `45 / 90 = 0.5`

Once you calculate the rotation using `Quaternion.Lerp()`, just multiply it with `Vector3.forward` and you get a new direction is that towards `_cameraTransform.forward`, but within the allowable angle.

Let's see what this could look like in code:

```cs
Vector3 GetDirectionWithinLimit(Vector3 initialDirection, Vector3 targetDirection, float angleLimit)
{
    float angleToTarget = Vector3.Angle(initialDirection, targetDirection);

    // If angle is within the limit, no need to do further calculations
    if (angleToTarget <= angleLimit)
    {
        return targetDirection;
    }

    // Calculate out a, b, and t
    Quaternion initialRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(initialDirection);
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
    float allowableRotationAmount = angleLimit / angleToTarget;

    // Now we can determine the angle-limited rotation
    Quaternion allowableRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialRotation, targetRotation, allowableRotationAmount);
    return allowableRotation * Vector3.forward;
}
```

How would you use this in your code? Well, a snippet might look like:

```cs
var playerAngle = _playerTransform.forward;
var camAngle = _cameraTransform.forward;
playerAngle.y = 0;
camAngle.y = 0;
var shootingDirection = GetDirectionWithinLimit(playerAngle, camAngle, 45);
```

After that, you can use this direction instead of the camera direction in `DrawProjection()` and elsewhere.

Comment: You don't need to go through Quaternion for that. You could use `Vector3.Slerp` on the directions directly and return that direction assuming that directions are already normalized you could do e.g. `return Vector3.Lerp(initialDirection, targetDirection, angleLimit / Vector3.Angle(initialDirection, targetDirection));` .. the `Slerp` works for directions without altering the magnitude. Also it already handles the clamping anyway as the factor is maximum `1` .. you might btw need to rather use `SignedAngle` and apply it via `Math.Abs` for the lerp but apply back the `Mathf.Sign` in the end

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! I'll have to keep Vector3.Slerp handy for when I need it in the future. Your comment may be worth turning into a new answer to surpass the existing ones, if the OP provides clarity on whether they're still having trouble.

Comment: I added one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601151/7111561) .. the signed angle was actually stupid :D the lerp doesn't care about the sign anyway ^^